# TabBarController delegate is not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

Can any one help me,
when i am using my UITabBarController delegate it is not working..

I called a delegate method like this..

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{

 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Comment: What's not working? Is nothing happening or does it crash? Have you put a breakpoint in the method to see if it's being called or is that your problem? We need more information :)

Comment: Did you correctly add the delegate?

Comment: Please be specific while asking question. It will confuse you if you look at your question after some days :). So please be more informative while asking question so that you may get what exactly you wanted :)

Answer (score 12):

If what you're doing is subclassing a UITabBarController, then... oddly enough... you can get it working by setting itself as a delegate:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.delegate = self;
}
```

Then the didSelectViewController action will fire normally:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSLog(@"View Changed");
}
```

Don't forget to add your UITabBarControllerDelegate class to your .h file:

```
@interface MyTabBarController : UITabBarController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@end
```

Comment: Yes, it sure seems counterintuitive that a controller would need a delegate especially when that controller is also its delegate

Comment: i follow the above steps but no success.i'm handling uitabbar programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using tab bar customizing by extending UITabBarController and trying to change tab bar selected index programmatically then it will not call delegates.

Please see the note inside "UITabBarDelegate":

```
// Note: called when a new view is selected by the user (but not programmatically)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for most of the issues related to this delegate not firing. +1

Answer (score 1):

This might help you

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    tabBarController.delegate=self;
    // Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Read the documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/) to get a deeper understanding of the relationships between navigation controllers, tabBar controllers, and the view and navigation hierarchy.

Then review the code you've provided.  Which view/controller is the container? You are popping the navigationController of self, which is not the same as the tabBarController.  I don't think you actually need this method if you are looking to switch between tabs.

Try commenting out this method.  It is an optional method in the UITabBarController delegate protocol.  If you comment it out, you should get the default behavior of the tab controller, which should be to select the appropriate viewController and switch to the new view.

You typically only need to use this method if you want some action taken as you switch between view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

specify

`UITabbarcontrollerDelegate` in .h file

then

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

tabBarController.delegate=self;

// Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
}
```